# Where's the DLL for SportsStore.UnitTests?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dll, asp.net-mvc-2

I reading Steven Sanderson's book, Pro Asp.NET MVC 2 Framework. I'm on page 116 and I'm running into trouble trying to use NUnit.

The book says that I should locate the DLL for SportsStore.UnitTests (one of three projects in the SportsStore solution.) But when i go to SportsStore\SportsStore.UnitTests\bin\Debug\ there is no dll to be found. Am I missing something obvious?

thanks SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with that book or with that sample solution but it sounds like that unit testing project did not build. Perhaps it's not configured to build by default or some other project it depends on had a build error.

Comment: I decided to continue with the book. the next step had me add some parameters to the controller which made it possible to build the project without errors. Lo and behold, DLLs appeared right where they were supposed to be. Thanks for the tip getting the test project to build.